# How use Laravel Language Translation in controller as constant?

Tags: laravel, localization, translation

Is it possible to use Laravel Language Translator (Localization) in controller as constant? Below attempt, example that does not work:

```
class SearchApproval extends Controller
{
    private $request;

    const stage_1 = Lang::get('message.failed');
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

trans it's a global function, so you can use it directly from your controller

```
trans('messages.failed');
```

but this won't work as constant, so you can use it like this:

```
class SearchApproval extends Controller
{
    private $request;

    const stage_1 = 'message.failed';

    public function xxx(){
        $whatever = trans(self::stage_1);
    }
}
```

UPDATED:

You can use this  __('Your Text') inside the controller.

Answer (score 4):

Use `trans('message.failed')` instead of `Lang::get('message.failed')` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-trans

Comment: Doesnt work: Constant expression contains invalid operations. The whole thing is that it is CONSTANT